# jQuery UI add droppable event listener while hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to add droppable event listener while dragging one object and hovering droppable object.

Here is my code:

```
$('.will-be-drag').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        $('.will-be-drop').hover(function () {
            $(this).droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    let item = ui.draggable;
                    console.log(item[0])
                    item.detach().appendTo($(this));
                }
            });
        }, function () {
            $(this).droppable('disable');
        });

    }
});
```

And my HTML is like that:

```
<div class="will-be-drag"></div>
<div class="will-be-drag"></div>
<div class="will-be-drag"></div>

<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= 3000; $i++){
?>
    <div class="will-be-drop"></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

I'm doing that because of performance issues. I have 3k droppable object and it's freezing while dragging. It must add `droppable` eventlistener with only dragging `$('.will-be-drag')` object and hovering `$('.will-be-drop')`.

With this code It only adds while hover not while dragging.

How can I do it?

I want javascript to breathe, it's being late when setting 3k droppable objects. There are only 30-40 draggable element. It's a table.

Comment: `$('.will-be-drop').not(this).draggable("disable");` ?

Comment: No, I want to add droppable only hovering items

Comment: can you put html code as well?

Comment: Ok let me put the PHP code

Comment: This is not the best way to make function work. I would assign droppable when the page initializes and then you can adjust the `accept` option or keep them disabled until hover.

Comment: I think jQuery ui add all of them event listener, and it's trying to handle the all of these event listeners

Comment: @sundowatch yes an event listerner will be added to each object. If you use `disable`, it's off until you `enabled`. I still think you should initialize them all, disable them, and then enable the ones that are visible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Hover example:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable();
  $("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this)
        .find("p")
        .html("Dropped!");
    }
  }).hover(function(e) {
    // IN
    $(this)
      .addClass("ui-state-highlight");
  }, function(e) {
    // OUT
    $(this)
      .removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

#droppable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```

You can see that when you mouse over the droppable, it highlights. When you drag, it doesn't. I suspect the `hover` event cannot bubble up over the persistent `mousedown` event.

Would suggest this:

```js
$(function() {
  function makeDrops(n) {
    var t = $(".ui-widget").eq(1);
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      $("<div>", {
        id: "drop-" + i,
        class: "will-be-drop ui-widget-content"
      }).appendTo(t);
    }
  }

  function inViewport(element, detectPartial) {
    element = $(element);
    detectPartial = (!!detectPartial); // if null or undefined, default to false

    var viewport = $(window),
      vpWidth = viewport.width(),
      vpHeight = viewport.height(),
      vpTop = viewport.scrollTop(),
      vpBottom = vpTop + vpHeight,
      vpLeft = viewport.scrollLeft(),
      vpRight = vpLeft + vpWidth,

      elementOffset = element.offset(),
      elementTopArea = elementOffset.top + ((detectPartial) ? element.height() : 0),
      elementBottomArea = elementOffset.top + ((detectPartial) ? 0 : element.height()),
      elementLeftArea = elementOffset.left + ((detectPartial) ? element.width() : 0),
      elementRightArea = elementOffset.left + ((detectPartial) ? 0 : element.width());

    return ((elementBottomArea <= vpBottom) && (elementTopArea >= vpTop)) && ((elementRightArea <= vpRight) && (elementLeftArea >= vpLeft));
  }

  function markVisible(c) {
    c.each(function(i, el) {
      if (inViewport(el, true)) {
        $(el).addClass("visible");
      }
    });
  }

  makeDrops(3000);

  $(".will-be-drop").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      let item = ui.draggable;
      console.log("Drag Item " + item.text().trim() + " dropped to " + $(this).attr("id"));
      item.detach().appendTo($(this));
    },
    over: function() {
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
    },
    out: function() {
      $(this).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
    }
  }).droppable("disable");

  $('.will-be-drag').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(e, ui) {
      markVisible($(".will-be-drop"));
      $(".will-be-drop.visible").droppable("enable");
    },
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      $(".will-be-drop.visible").droppable("disable").removeClass("visible");
      markVisible($(".will-be-drop"));
      $(".will-be-drop.visible").droppable("enable");
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      $(".will-be-drop").droppable("disable");
      $(".will-be-drop.ui-state-highlight").removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.will-be-drag {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.will-be-drop {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="will-be-drag ui-widget-content">A</div>
  <div class="will-be-drag ui-widget-content">B</div>
  <div class="will-be-drag ui-widget-content">C</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
</div>
```

You can also initialize some as droppable with `:visible` or some other condition to reduce memory overhead. Just remember to also destroy them otherwise you will just pile on the memory issue as the user moves through the page while dragging.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, but there is no difference on the performance, it really freezes

Comment: @sundowatch no I had not tested it with 3000 items. I have updated my answer and yes, it's a bit slow on performance yet the script did not halt. If there are more elements on the page and other scripts, then memory resource might drop on some browsers to a state where the script is no longer responsive. If that's the case, you might consider initializing and destroying droppable based on the scroll value, and turn on a group of them. Maybe use the `:visible` selector.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, but if I can manage to get the cell(will-be-drop) while dragging everything would be fine

Comment: @sundowatch due to the click-n-hold activity created by dragging, some events, like hover, do not always trigger properly. So mouse position or scroll position conditions might be better to look at during drag.

Comment: @sundowatch updated with a expanded example regarding hover.

Comment: @sundowatch another much larger update that enables only the droppables in the viewport.